# ConfigurationErrorsException while deploy web based URL Routing web site with .Net3.5 SP1

Tags: url-routing, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am using URL Routing for web based form with .NET 3.5 SP1. Its work fine on my devlopement machine but when I host it with windowxp cause exception. even I m unable to open home page. any one plz what is the problem..

```
Public Sub HyperLinkRoutes()
  System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.Add("Kms_Hyperlink_Document", New System.Web.Routing.Route("GetFiles/Kms_Hyperlink_Document/{DocumentID}", New RouteHandler("~/KMS/PreviewHyperlink.aspx")))
End Sub

public class RouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public RouteHandler()
    {

    }
    public RouteHandler(string virtualPath)
    {
        _virtualPath = virtualPath;
    }

    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        if (requestContext.RouteData.Values["DocumentID"] != null)
        {
            var  display = BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(
                            _virtualPath, typeof(Page)) as Page    ;
            if (display != null)
            {
                //display.DocumentID  = requestContext.RouteData.Values["DocumentID"] as string;
                foreach (var value in requestContext.RouteData.Values)
                {
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Items[value.Key] = value.Value;
                } 

                return display;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    string _virtualPath;
}
```

Exception information: 
Exception type: ConfigurationErrorsException 
    Exception message: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Stack trace:    at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective)
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory()
   at System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig)
   at System.Web.Compilation.WebDirectoryBatchCompiler..ctor(VirtualDirectory vdir)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectoryInternal(VirtualDirectory vdir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.BatchCompileWebDirectory(VirtualDirectory vdir, VirtualPath virtualDir, Boolean ignoreErrors)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean noAssert)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.System.Web.IHttpHandlerFactory2.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHttpHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath path, String pathTranslated, Boolean useAppConfig)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MapHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 0):

You need IIS 6.0 or higher for that stuff. XP only provides IIS 5.1. You could try the IIS Express thingy.

Comment: @Harendra: Not on XP you arent!

Comment: ya u r rite but same issue with Vista...and i m using IIS 7 on vista machine. so it seems not a IIS issue.

Comment: yes work fine on developement machine (debugging mode) but not working on image or in hosting environment.

Comment: @Harendra: Well, you are using XP for hosting, that is clear why it does nto work, now what is 'image' ?

Comment: @leppie: for testing we are use different machine or virtaul images with different OS. we have a web installeer that publish code and also installed pre-requisite.

Comment: @Harendra: Check that the 'image' 's Application Pool is set to integrated mode and not classic mode. All I can think of. Check hostheaders too, if they are used.

Comment: Thanks leppie, i got it its different dll version issue. issue with Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll version due to different sQL version on build machine and hosting envirnment. removing the dll from bin solved the problem.

Comment: @Harendra: Glad you got it sorted :)